# Django apps and subdirs

Tags: python, django

In Django I'm trying to divide one app (so only app is in installed_apps) into several subdirs, with the following structure:

```
app
    views.py
app\subdir1
    views.py
app\subdir2
    views.py
```

the file app\views.py consist only of

```
from subdir1.views import *
```

so I collapse the namespace of app.subdir1.views into app.views. However that's not the desired solution, I rather use

```
import subdir1.views
```

and not collapse the namespaces, however this construct makes Django complain with the error "Could not import app.views.subdir1.json. Parent module app.views.subdir1 does not exist."
which is of course correct, Because that parent module does not exist.

So the question I would like to raise: is this dir structure possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, you can use `app.subdir1.views.foo` in `urls.py` then and completely avoid importing in `app/views.py`.

Maybe `__init__.py` file is missing in one of those directories?

Comment: I tried and yes, the view works, however trying to use syncdb fails because app\subdir1 is not seen as an application. Adding app\subdir1 in installed_apps fixes this... but that's the part I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you just serve views in your subdir's you would not have this problem. If you got models as well then there is no other way than adding it to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: You are dead right Torsten, I see it doesn't work, however I can't explain why it isn't working. Because in app I place a models.py woth lines like: from subdir1.models import *
and as far as i know this 'dissolves' the scope of that subdir1 into app scope. So probably some learning for me ahead ;-)